# Overriding Laravel RedirectResponse

Tags: php, laravel, oauth, urlencode, laravel-socialite

I'm extending Laravel Socialiste for a new Oauth provider and having trouble with the simple issue of altering the authorize url.

The url generated by the `RedirectResponse` has `%2C` instead of `+`, e.g., https://mycustomerprovider.com/oauth/authorize?scope=blah%2Cblahagain, for the scopes delimiter and thus fails with the particular provider I'm using, in this example `mycustomprovider`.

Anyone know how to modify this authorize url to change the `%2C` to `+`?

`return Socialite::driver('mycustomprovider')->redirect();`

If you `var_dump(Socialite::driver('mycustomprovider')->redirect())`, here's what it contains:

```
RedirectResponse {#886 ▼
  #targetUrl: "http://"
  +headers: ResponseHeaderBag {#888 ▶}
  #content: """
    <!DOCTYPE html>\n
    <html>\n
        <head>\n
            <meta charset="UTF-8" />\n
            <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=https://mycustomerprovider.com/oauth/authorize?scope=blah%2Cblahagain" />\n
    \n
            <title>Redirecting to https://mycustomerprovider.com/oauth/authorize?scope=blah%2Cblahagain</title>\n
        </head>\n
        <body>\n
            Redirecting to <a href="https://mycustomerprovider.com/oauth/authorize?scope=blah%2Cblahagain</a>.\n
        </body>\n
    </html>
    """
  #version: "1.0"
  #statusCode: 302
  #statusText: "Found"
  #charset: null
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a simple **middleware** for this

```
php artisan make:middleware ReplaceMiddleware
```

In **App\Http\Middleware\ReplaceMiddleware.php**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    $response = $next($request);
    $response->setContent(str_replace('%2C','+',$response->getContent()));
    return $response;
}
```

In your **Controller**. In **__construct** method

```
$this->middleware('replace_response');
```

In App\Http\Kernel.php. Add to $**routeMiddleware** array

```
'replace_response' => \App\Http\Middleware\ReplaceMiddleware::class,
```

You've done. Try it!